# How to give sumo options with sumo-launchd.py?

Tags: veins, sumo

I am trying to give `--max-depart-delay` option with sumo but doesn't proceed. How I can pass options to `sumo` with `sumo-launchd.py` ?

I have tried following command

`sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo --max-depart-delay -1`

Answer (score 2):

`sumo-launchd.py` executes the command given by the `-c` option. By default this is `sumo` which is resolved by searching your `$PATH` variable.

When you execute the given command, python interprets `--max-depart-delay` as another argument for `sumo-launchd.py` which does not make sense because it does not exist:

> Usage: sumo-launchd.py [options]
>
> sumo-launchd.py: error: no such option: --max-depart-delay

Therefore, you want to indicate that `max-depart-delay` is an option for the SuMO command to be executed and not for the launch daemon by surrounding it with `''` or `""`:

`sumo-launchd.py -vv -c 'sumo --max-depart-delay -1'`

`sumo-launchd.py -vv -c "sumo --max-depart-delay -1"`

> Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log
>
> Listening on port 9999

Comment: I am getting following error now:

`Could not start SUMO (sumo --max-depart-delay -1 -c test.sumo.cfg): [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: it seems SuMO can't find your config file.I recommend you test the command which you want the launch daemon to execute manually beforehand. In your case this would be `sumo  --max-part-delay -1 -c test.sumo.cfg`.

Comment: I had tested the command, `sumo --max-part-delay -1 -c test.sumo.cfg` it works fine. I tried many other options with sumo-launchd.py but nothing works. With any option, i get same error `No such file or directory`

Comment: The `sumo-launchd.py` is a script to launch a SuMO deamon which waits for input from the `TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd` module. Every input including the scenario and config files are sent to the deamon via the TraCI protocol (see http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/sumo-launchd/) and therefore are specified in `omnetpp.ini` and not directly via arguments.

Comment: so where do I specify --max-part-delay option?

Comment: Maybe, my comment was not clear enough: SuMO parameters like `max-part-delay` are specified via the command to be executed (as shown above). However, the scenario dependent files like `test.sumo.cfg` are specified in the [launchd config file](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/examples/veins/erlangen.launchd.xml) which in turn is specified in [`omnetpp.ini`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L49) because it is given to SuMO via the TraCI protocol. Thus, put the parameters in the command and the scenario in the launchd config file.

Comment: I get what you are implying to tell me but the config file is defined in the xml file since the command `sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo` works absolutely great but not `sumo-launchd.py -vv -c "sumo --max-depart-delay -1" ` or `sumo-launchd.py -vv -c 'sumo --max-depart-delay -1'`

Comment: Both command versions you gave should and do indeed work perfectly fine, at least on my machine. Since you accepted this answer, I thought your issue was solved.

Comment: Works for me: `julian@linux: ./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c "sumo --max-depart-delay -1"
 --> 
Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log
Listening on port 9999`
&
`julian@linux: ./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c 'sumo --max-depart-delay -1' 
 --> 
Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log
Listening on port 9999`

Comment: This works for me as well but after starting the simulation I get errors.

Comment: I have tried everything I do get `./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c 'sumo --max-depart-delay -1' --> Logging to /tmp/sumo-launchd.log Listening on port 9999` but as soon as the simulation starts I get error `Could not start SUMO (sumo --max-depart-delay -1 -c test.sumo.cfg): [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I really need --max-depart-delay for my project.