# launch ./veins_launchd with sumo option "-scale"

Tags: veins, sumo

I want launch launch ./veins_launchd with sumo option "-scale".

This is my launch command:

```
$ ./veins_launchd -vv --command='sumo --scale 6'
```

This command execute correctly.

But as soon as I start running simulation, it pop follow error message:

```
Seed is 0
Finding free port number...
Claiming lock on port
...found port 38677
Starting SUMO (sumo --scale 6 -c due.actuated.sumocfg) on port 38677, seed 0
Releasing lock on port
Cleaning up
Result: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<status>
    <exit-code>-1</exit-code>
    <start>1651068679</start>
    <end>1651068679</end>
    <status>Could not start SUMO (sumo --scale 6 -c due.actuated.sumocfg): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sumo --scale 6': 'sumo --scale 6'</status>
    <stdout><![CDATA[]]></stdout>
    <stderr><![CDATA[]]></stderr>
</status>
"
```

I have read link follow:
[How to give sumo options with sumo-launchd.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709095/how-to-give-sumo-options-with-sumo-launchd-py)

My problem is almost the same with his.

Since that problem is post at 2017 and not have been solved, I decide to repost this problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the line

```
<scale value="6"/>
```

to your due.actuated.sumocfg.